# mock require of oracledb using proxyquire to unit test node.js app

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, proxyquire

Please help to fix the below issue:

I am trying to unit test the dbAdapter module using mocha.

**dbAdapter to connect to oracle and execute sql commands** (dbAdapter.js)

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

let doConnect = function(callback) {
    oracledb.getConnection(config, callback); 
};


let execute_selectquery = function(query, results) {
    this.query = query;

    this.execute = function(connection, callback) {
        connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }else {
                callback(result);
            }

        })
};
```

**unit test to test the select query:** (test.js)

```
describe(`test proxyquire`, function() {
            const proxyquire =  require('proxyquire')
            let dbAdapter
            let oracledbStub;

            before(function() {

                oracledbStub = {
                    model: function() {
                        return {
                            updateDb: function(id, first, last, callback) {
                                callback(null, 'done'); 
                            } 
                        };
                    } 
                };

            dbAdapter = proxyquire('../controllers/dbAdapter.js', {'oracledb': oracledbStub});
            });  

            it.only(`test route`, function(done) {
                let query = "select * from users";
                db.execute_selectquery(query, function(err, result){
                    console.log(result)
                })

            }) 
})
```

In the above unit test I have used proxyquire so that I can use my mocked oracledbStub instead of oracledb in dbAdapter.js

When I run the unit test I get the below error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
      at Function.getConnection (node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:295:10)
      at Function.getConnection (node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js:99:19)
      at doConnect (controllers/dbConnection/oracleAdapter.js:47:14)
      at fn (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:641:34)
      at Immediate.<anonymous> (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:557:34)
```

I followed the below blog:
http://www.devblogrbmz.com/nodejs-mocking-with-proxyquire/

I believe I might be missing some detail and have been stuck since a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the example that you based your code on, you'll notice that `mongooseStub` is an object with a `model` method that is meant to override the `model` method that's included with Mongoose. If that method doesn't exist on the stub, then the method from Mongoose would have been used instead.

In your case, you've defined the `oracleStub` with an object that has a `model` function. However, oracledb doesn't have a model method - so that's not going to do anything. Your stub should include a `getConnection` function since that's what you're trying to override from the base class (oracledb).

This will get tricky as you then have to have a stub for a connection object and its methods, like execute. The more methods you use in the actual library, the more work you'll have stubbing it all out.

There's a similar question here: [How to stub oracledb with sinon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180905/how-to-stub-oracledb-with-sinon)